# Select table rows between 2 rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quick js\jquery question.

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="test">
<tr class="divider"><td>Set 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
<tr class="divider"><td>Set 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 6</td></tr>
<tr class="divider"><td>Set 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 7</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 8</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 9</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to select only the 3 rows between the rows with the class "divider".

I started a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQhBP/1/

I am using nextUntil but it doesn't seem to be working right

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nextUntil()` definitely works:

```
var pull = $('.divider:first').nextUntil('.divider');
console.log(pull);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZQhBP/17/).

And to move those rows and insert to a new table element, after the first:

```
var pull = $('.divider:first').nextUntil('.divider');
console.log(pull);

$('<table />').insertAfter('table:first').append('<tbody />').html(pull);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZQhBP/21/).

And, if you'd rather copy/clone to a new table:

```
var pull = $('.divider:first').nextUntil('.divider');
console.log(pull);

$('<table />').insertAfter('table:first').append('<tbody />').html(pull.clone(true,true));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZQhBP/27/).

References:

- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).
- [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).

Comment: what does console.log(pull) do?

Comment: You're absolutely welcome; I'm glad to have been of help! =) `console.log(pull)` echoes/prints the variable `pull` to the console. It's much like `alert(pull)` except it's less intrusive. Look at your JavaScript console (F12 for IE and Chrome), Firebug and Dragonfly should have a comparable option, too. Though I don't know the shortcuts for those browsers.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQhBP/4/

`$('#test tr').not('.divider');`

Comment: This selects all the rows I was hoping to only select a set of rows between specific divider rows.  eg: Row 1 Row 2 Row 3

Comment: On what events, page-load? Clicks?

Comment: @MarkK Like this: `$('.divider:nth-child(1)').nextUntil('.divider');`

Comment: page-load.  End game is to take that chunk of code and put it somewhere else on the page which I know how to do, i just need to get the code first.